# InnoDB vs MyISAM for small table Wordpress blog

Tags: mysql, wordpress, database-design, innodb, myisam

I have moved a WordPress site from a not so good hosting company to one to a host that specializes in WordPress hosting and performance. The old host did not allow InnoDB tables only MyISAM. Would like to take advantage of as many performance enhancements as possible. With that in mind which default WordPress tables which are best converted to InnoDB and which are best left as MyISAM?

Comment: I think it's all or none.

Comment: I have read post where people have both types so I am looking for advice on whether there are any WordPress tables that benefit from the MyIsam format or any that need to InnoDB in particular because of foreign keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- MySQL is moving toward getting rid of MyISAM.
- If you have a "small" site, you will be hard pressed to see a difference in performance.
- Perhaps the best performance boost comes from changing the schema for wp_postmeta:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta
- More on moving from MyISAM to InnoDB:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb

Comment: Thanks for the advice Rick, appreciate it!